# Java consuming a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, jax-ws

I've been asked to rebuild our customer portal, using gwt and connecting to our data using various webservices set up on the server.

I generated all the proxy classes usign the WSDL and Jax-WS/wsimport utility, however when i make the below call:

```
ReportingApiSoap soap = api.getReportingApiSoap();      
ArrayOfReport returnValues = soap.getReports(serverCredentials, true);
```

My returnValues object is null.  I know the webservice itself works because I was able to test it with the same parameters I'm passing in now.

I was previously have some issues sending data to the webservice; that turning out to be the namespaces weren't lining up as they needed to.  I suspect something similar is happening here, but haven't been able to figure out what yet.

Anyone ever run into something similiar before?  Or if not any idea how I can check the raw xml I'm getting out of the webservice call?  That way I can track the problem a step furthur.

-Ian

My Credentials object:

```
public class ApiCredentials {

 @XmlElement(name = "Id", namespace="http://mycompany.com")
 protected String id;
 @XmlElement(name = "Login", namespace="http://mycompany.com")
 protected String login;
 @XmlElement(name = "Password", namespace="http://mycompany.com")
 protected String password;

 ...
}
```

ArrayofReport:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ArrayOfReport", propOrder = {
 "report"
})
public class ArrayOfReport {

 @XmlElement(name = "Report", nillable = true)
 protected List<Report> report;

 public List<Report> getReport() {
    if (report == null) {
        report = new ArrayList<Report>();
    }
    return this.report;
 }

}
```

Webservice call:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetReports", action = "http://mycompany.com/GetReports")
@WebResult(name = "GetReportsResult", targetNamespace = "http://mycompany.com")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "GetReports", targetNamespace = "http://mycompany.com", className = "com.mycompany.customerportal.server.GetReports")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetReportsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://mycompany.com", className = "com.mycompany.customerportal.server.GetReportsResponse")
public ArrayOfReport getReports(
    @WebParam(name = "credentials", targetNamespace = "http://mycompany.com")
    ApiCredentials credentials,
    @WebParam(name = "includeFields", targetNamespace = "http://mycompany.com")
    boolean includeFields);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend creating a mock web service (e.g. using [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)). This will allow you to see and validate the request XML against your WSDL. You can cut'n'paste/edit mock responses to the client to see the effect.

JAX-WS implementations are a dime-a-dozen, so any further options depend on the client technology in your runtime. I would ensure that validation is enabled (this might be implemented as a [feature](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceFeature.html), for example).

Comment: What validation do you mean?  I'm just using generated proxy classes I moved into my client project, haven't done anything special to them at all.

Comment: @Ian Jacobs - validation of the SOAP response XML by the JAX-WS client code is optional (see the spec). If the response does not conform to the contract defined by the WSDL, an exception will be thrown when validation is enabled.

Comment: Good idea with the mock web service, I hadn't thought of that.  However I'm still not getting anything back in my objects.  I implemented the client side validation as discussed here: http://metro.java.net/guide/Schema_Validation.html  but nothing comes up as an exception.  Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not really sure what happened but I re-generate the proxy classes and everything seems to be working now.   Thanks for your help!